# Cant get my regex to validate my html form

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a html form with some client validation and some server validation (regex).
But i cant get the regex to work with the html form, and it possible to submit the form without any inputs. I have been stuck on this for hours, argh. Any one that can understand why?

This is the HTML form

```
    <form action="brukerinfo.php" method="post" name="kontaktskjema" id="kontaktskjema">

        <h3>Registrer din informasjon her</h3>
        <div>
                <label>
                        <span>Fornavn: (påkrevd)</span>
                        <input name="fornavn" id="fornavn" placeholder="Fornavn" type="text" tabindex="1" pattern="^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]{2,}$"
                        title="Fornavn er påkrevd, og må være minst 2 tegn" required autofocus> 
                </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                <label>
                        <span>Etternavn: (påkrevd)</span>
                        <input name="etternavn" id="etternavn" placeholder="Etternavn" type="text" tabindex="2" pattern="^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]{2,}$"
                        title="Etternavn er påkrevd, og må være minst 2 tegn og kan ikke bestå av mellomrom" required>
                </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                <label>
                        <span>Email:</span>
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Skriv inn din mailadresse"  tabindex="3">
                </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                <label>
                        <span>Telefon: (påkrevd) </span>
                        <input name="telefon" id="telefon" placeholder="Skriv inn ditt telefonnummer" type="tel" tabindex="4" 
                         pattern="[0-9]{8}" title="Må bestå av 8 siffer" required>
                </label>
        </div>
          <div>
                <label> 
                        <span>DOB:</span>
                        <input name="fdag" id="fdag" type="date" tabindex="5" required>
                </label>
        </div>

        <div>
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="kontaktskjema-submit">Send inn</button>
        </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>

enter code here
```

And this i the regex validation,

```
 <?
//preg_match for email
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $emailregex = '[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}';

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    if (!preg_match($emailregex, $email)) {
       echo 'invalid email';
    }
     }

    //validating the phone number
    $telefon = $_POST ['telefon'];
    $telmatch = array('98979695' ,'97969594','90807090','90908080','40908070','45674849','46573823','45343456');

    if(isset($_POST['telefon'])){
        if(!preg_match($telefon, $telmatch)){

            echo 'invalid phone number';

            }
        }

    //validatin the date
    $fdag = $_POST['fdag'];

    if(isset($_POST['fdag'])) {

    if(preg_match('/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-^[0-9]{4}$/', $fdag))

    {
         if(date(Y, time()) - date(Y,strtotime($fdag)) > 16){
            echo 'invalid date';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'you have to be at least 16';
        }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: So, you're echo-ing validation errors but where do you process them ?

Comment: why you are not using default library that is provide by languages. as for jquery you can use validate.js it is automatically make your life. It may if you want validation in one fields then its okay. But for server side i would suggest use `PHP_FILTERS` to match email pattern.

Comment: Good question, haha. I have include the php validation file in the php file that contains the html form. how can I process the echo in the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can validate email in php by using [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($email)) {
     if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo 'invalid email';
     }
}
```